# Unable to load non-existant components from PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish-3

After upgrading to the PrimeFaces 4.0-SNAPSHOT I'm getting this stacktrace whenever I deploy my application :

```
WARNING: WEB9052: Unable to load class org.primefaces.component.galleria.GalleriaContent, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.galleria.GalleriaContent
WARNING: WEB9052: Unable to load class org.primefaces.component.galleria.GalleriaOverlay, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.galleria.GalleriaOverlay
WARNING: WEB9052: Unable to load class org.primefaces.component.submenu.Submenu, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.submenu.Submenu
WARNING: WEB9052: Unable to load class org.primefaces.component.resources.Resources, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.resources.Resources
WARNING: WEB9052: Unable to load class org.primefaces.component.sheet.Sheet, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.sheet.Sheet
WARNING: WEB9052: Unable to load class org.primefaces.component.menuitem.MenuItem, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.menuitem.MenuItem
WARNING: WEB9052: Unable to load class org.primefaces.component.galleria.GalleriaContentRenderer, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.galleria.GalleriaContentRenderer
WARNING: WEB9052: Unable to load class org.primefaces.component.galleria.GalleriaOverlayRenderer, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.galleria.GalleriaOverlayRenderer
WARNING: WEB9052: Unable to load class org.primefaces.component.sheet.SheetRenderer, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.sheet.SheetRenderer
WARNING: WEB9052: Unable to load class org.primefaces.component.galleria.GalleriaContentRenderer, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.galleria.GalleriaContentRenderer
WARNING: WEB9052: Unable to load class org.primefaces.component.galleria.GalleriaOverlayRenderer, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.galleria.GalleriaOverlayRenderer
WARNING: WEB9052: Unable to load class org.primefaces.component.sheet.SheetRenderer, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.sheet.SheetRenderer
WARNING: WEB9052: Unable to load class org.primefaces.component.galleria.GalleriaContentRenderer, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.galleria.GalleriaContentRenderer
WARNING: WEB9052: Unable to load class org.primefaces.component.galleria.GalleriaOverlayRenderer, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.galleria.GalleriaOverlayRenderer
WARNING: WEB9052: Unable to load class org.primefaces.component.sheet.SheetRenderer, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.component.sheet.SheetRenderer
INFO: Initialisation de Mojarra 2.1.23 ( 20130613-1525 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.1.23@11994) pour le contexte «/myapp»
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 4.0-SNAPSHOT
INFO: Using OmniFaces version 1.6-SNAPSHOT-20130701
INFO: PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter INFO: loaded (conf ok)
INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [myapp] at [/myapp]
INFO: myapp was successfully deployed in ~ 796 milliseconds.
```

I know the error is that it's looking for a class (and not finding it), but these classes are not present in the newer versions of PrimeFaces.  Looking into the jar files, it's clear that these do not exits.

My question is more focused on why is PrimeFaces, (or something else?) trying to load these classes.

I am running on Glassfish 3.1.2.2.

Comment: Are you referencing this classes into your code?

Comment: @XtremeBiker No never. I'm developing in Eclipse and used the file search functionality to see if I was ever using these or if they were left from legacy code or what not, but it always comes out as nothing found.  Unless these classes are referenced from other modules/tags/components.